# want to get following following JSON output

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables which are as follows:

**quote_glass_types**

```
id    |   name
1         clear float glass
2         Tinted glass
```

**quote_glass_type_thickness**

```
id    |   quote_glass_type_id_fk        |     thickness
 1                1                               5mm
 2                1                               8mm
 3                2                               5mm
 4                2                               8mm
```

Now, I would like to join these two tables and get Json as follows:

```
[
{
  id:1,
  name: "clear float glass",
  thickness:{"5mm","8mm" }
 },
{ 
 id:2
 name:"tinted glass",
 thickness:{"5mm","8mm"}
 }
]
```

Till now I have done like this:

```
$glasssetting=\DB::table('quote_glass_types')
          ->join('quote_glass_type_thickness','quote_glass_type_thickness.quote_glass_type_id_fk','=','quote_glass_types.id')
          ->select('quote_glass_type_thickness.id','name','thickness')
          ->get();

return $glasssetting;
```

which gives JSON like:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Clear Float Glasss",
"thickness": "5mm"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Clear Float Glasss",
"thickness": "8mm"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Tinted glass",
"thickness": "5mm"
 },
  {
"id": 4,
"name": "Tinted glass",
"thickness": "8mm"
  }
 ]
```

How do I get the required json?

Comment: Why you are not using eloquent?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "how do I get the required json" ? what are you doing in your view page with that?

Comment: @Arminius I just want specific type of JSON response which I have written  above, after my database tables thank you.

Comment: maybe like this? json_encode($glasseting);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Eloquent for example

```
return App\QuoteGlassType::with('thickness')->get();
```

I dont know your Modelname but thats what you are looking for.
Of course make also sure to set the correct Relationships within your Model.